# Fill height of parent with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height

I'm working on some responsive design, where I have a `ul` with some `li` elements inside, with some varying text lengths. I want the `li` elements to fill the height of the `ul`, but am having some trouble with it. The `li` elements have a differing height, when the content of one of them becomes too long. An example can be found below:

```css
ul {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  width: 650px; 
  background: red;
}

li {
  background: orange;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Longer text here 1-2-3</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Payment</li>
  <li>Payment step 2</li>
  <li>Receipt</li>
</ul>
```

How do I make the `li` elements the same height, regardless of their content?

Comment: I'm not sure where in my post I said that @s.kuznetsov?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `align-items: center` with `align-items: stretch` in `ul`. And remove `height: 100%` in `li`.

```css
ul {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: stretch; 
  width: 650px; 
  background: red;
}

li {
  background: orange;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Longer text here 1-2-3</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Payment</li>
  <li>Payment step 2</li>
  <li>Receipt</li>
</ul>
```

As the item names suggest, this implies a menu with **links**?! I put `a` tag inside each `li` tag.

Inherit the `li` flex rule from the parent by adding `display: inherit`. And add this css that centers your punctures vertically:

```
ul li a {  
  margin: auto 0 auto 0;
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: stretch; 
  width: 650px; 
  background: red;
}

li {
  display: inherit; 
  background: orange;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

ul li a {  
  margin: auto 0 auto 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Longer text here 1-2-3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Payment</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Payment step 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Receipt</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nothing much to add - this fixed my problem entirely, althought I of course had to add `display: flex; align-items: center` to the `li` elements to keep the content centered in them. Thanks!

Comment: @Loyalar, If you center `li`, it will look uneven relative to elements that span more than one line.

Comment: That's definetly true, but it does look better in my case, but I understand it won't in all situations :)

Comment: @Loyalar To easily center anything, all you need is `display: flex` in the parent and `margin:auto` in the child (your target). Also `align-items` is already by default set to `stretch`, thus redundant.

Comment: @MatinSasan, quite right, but then the height of the <li> tags will not reach the height of the parent.

Comment: @Loyalar, Do you need such an arrangement of elements? - https://ibb.co/MkT0Gk9

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Yes, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Loyalar, I made a second snippet.